# Python - Parsing through a JSON file and storing it as a variable

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am not too familiar with Python and I am trying to understand how I can open a JSON file that contains keys and values that I need to open in a Python file and manipulate each value. Ultimately I would like to assign those values somewhere so I can use them to make a Python GUI (tkinter).

so far I have this for testing but get an error:

```
import json

with open('data2.json', "r") as f:
    for jsonObj in f:
        studentDict = json.load(jsonObj)
        studentsList.append(studentDict)


print("Printing each JSON things..")
for student in studentsList:
    print(str(student["name"], student["id"], student["year"]))
```

=====================================================================================

and my JSON file content is this:

```
[
  {
   "name": "jane",
   "id": "jdoe",
   "year": "sophomore"

  }
  {
   "name": "john",
   "id": "jsmith",
   "year": "senior"
  }
]
```

Comment: Your file is exactly one JSON object (assuming there really is a comma in between the objects).  Just do `with open('data2.json') as f:` / `obj = json.load(f)`.  Then you'll have the whole list.

Comment: And you don't need to call `str`.  All of those things are strings already.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

with open('data2.json', "r") as f:
    studentsList = json.load(f)


print("Printing each JSON things..")
for student in studentsList:
    print(student["name"], student["id"], student["year"])
```

Comment: thank you for your response Tim. I tried it exactly how you mentioned however I get a "TypeError: string indices must be integers" error.

Comment: That just means your JSON data does not look what you showed up there.  That data works fine.  Perhaps you should check your data again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
studentsList = []

with open('data2.json', "r") as f:
    for jsonObj in f:
        studentDict = json.loads(jsonObj)
        studentsList.append(studentDict)

print("Printing each JSON things..")
for student in studentsList[0]:
    print(str(student["name"], student["id"], student["year"]))
```

It's a nested list you got as a result of appending to studentsList:

```
[[{'name': 'jane', 'id': 'jdoe', 'year': 'sophomore'},
  {'name': 'john', 'id': 'jsmith', 'year': 'senior'}]]
```

So, in order for the loop to work properly, you have to index one level in before calling the dictionary keys. studentsList[0] gives you:

```
[{'name': 'jane', 'id': 'jdoe', 'year': 'sophomore'},
 {'name': 'john', 'id': 'jsmith', 'year': 'senior'}]
```

Now, each iteration in your loop will reference a dictionary object and you can start to call its keys without getting any error.